# PMCreateSession not creating print session

Tags: swift, macos

Trying to get printable rect for OS X app. Seems to involve creating a session, then a page format, validating the format, etc. Code compiles, but getting a status of -50 from PMCreateSession. Am I declaring printSession improperly? Normally don't have to deal so much with UnsafeMutablePointers.

Thanks!

```
    let printSession: UnsafeMutablePointer<PMPrintSession> = nil
    let pmPageFormat: UnsafeMutablePointer<PMPageFormat> = nil
    var status = PMCreateSession(printSession)
    status = PMCreatePageFormat(pmPageFormat)
    status = PMSessionDefaultPageFormat(printSession.memory, pmPageFormat.memory)
    let changed: UnsafeMutablePointer<DarwinBoolean> = nil
    status = PMSessionValidatePageFormat(printSession.memory, pmPageFormat.memory, changed)
    changed.destroy()
    var pRect = PMRect()
    status = PMGetAdjustedPageRect(pmPageFormat.memory, &pRect)

    Swift.print("pRect \(pRect)")

    status = PMRelease(pmPageFormat)
    status = PMRelease(printSession)
```

Comment: Works better when allocating the pointers. For example, let printSession = UnsafeMutablePointer<PMPrintSession>.alloc(1)  When printSession, pmPageFormat, and changed are declared and allocated like that, actually getting a reasonable rect (0, 0, 734, 576). But still crashing on the PMRelease call and uncertain why.

Comment: For now, replaced the PMRelease(printSession) (and other PMRelease) with printSession.destroy() and printSession.dealloc(1). No obvious harmful effects, but uncertain if that's the right thing to do or why PMRelease crashes.

Answer (score 0):

> Am I declaring printSession improperly?

One could acquire a `PMPrintSession` as follows:

```swift
// create a C Null pointer of type PMPrintSession
let printSession = unsafeBitCast(0, to: PMPrintSession.self)
// pass by & converts PMPrintSession to UnsafeMutablePointer<PMPrintSession>
PMCreateSession(&printSession)
…
// recast printSession to release memory
PMRelease( PMObject(printSession) )
```

Alternately, a `PMPrintSession` can be accessed from the Cocoa `NSPrintInfo`:

```swift
let printInfo = NSPrintInfo.shared()
let printSession = PMPrintSession(printInfo.pmPrintSession())
```

> Normally don't have to deal so much with UnsafeMutablePointers

For information more information on using an `UnsafeMutablePointer` see StackOverflow ["How to use UnsafeMutablePointer in Swift?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44893912/how-to-use-unsafemutablepointeropaquepointer-in-swift)

For a complete example of using Core Printing with Swift see [004.42Apple_CorePrintingExample](https://github.com/marc-medley/004.42Apple_CorePrintingExample) on GitHub.

Comment: Thanks for response. I'll get back into this code as time permits (a year ago seems like a lifetime!) and try to verify suggestions and accept if I do or if see other comments that this is the right approach. Not ignoring it or hesitating to accept; just on deadlines with other stuff at the moment. Thank you.