# How to use UnsafeMutablePointer<OpaquePointer> in Swift?

Tags: swift, macos

How does one use an `UnsafeMutablePointer<OpaquePointer>` in Swift with some Core Foundation framework?  Why have an `UnsafeMutablePointer<OpaquePointer>`?

Given, general: some `UnsafeMutablePointer<SomeType>` where `typealias SomeType = OpaquePointer`

*Specific Example API*

```swift
// SOURCE: import ApplicationServices.PrintCore
typealias PMPrinter = OpaquePointer
func PMSessionGetCurrentPrinter(_ printSession: PMPrintSession, _ currentPrinter: UnsafeMutablePointer<PMPrinter>)
func PMPrinterGetPaperList(PMPrinter, UnsafeMutablePointer<Unmanaged<CFArray>?>)
```

*Specific Example Use Case: get list of papers supported by a printer*

```swift
let printInfo = NSPrintInfo.shared()
let printSession = PMPrintSession(printInfo.pmPrintSession())
var currentPrinterOptional: PMPrinter? = nil
PMSessionGetCurrentPrinter(printSession, &currentPrinterOptional!)
guard let currentPrinter = currentPrinterOptional else { return }

// Get the array of pre-defined PMPapers this printer supports.
// PMPrinterGetPaperList(PMPrinter, UnsafeMutablePointer<Unmanaged<CFArray>?>)
var paperListUnmanaged: Unmanaged<CFArray>?
PMPrinterGetPaperList(currentPrinter, &paperListUnmanaged)
guard let paperList = paperListUnmanaged?.takeUnretainedValue() as [AnyObject]? else { return }
```

### Observed Errors

*What compiles does not run.  What seems like (maybe) reasonable syntax does not compile.*

The above example gets the following (expected) Runtime *"fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"*.

Some select other attempts:

```swift
// Compile Error: Address of variable 'currentPrinter' taken before is is initialized
var currentPrinter: PMPrinter
PMSessionGetCurrentPrinter(printSession, &currentPrinter)

// Compile Error: Nil cannot initialze specified type 'PMPrinter' (aka 'OpaquePointer')
var currentPrinter: PMPrinter = nil
PMSessionGetCurrentPrinter(printSession, &currentPrinter)

// Compile Error: Variable 'currentPrinterPtr' used before being initialized
var currentPrinterPtr: UnsafeMutablePointer<PMPrinter>
PMSessionGetCurrentPrinter(printSession, currentPrinterPtr)

// Compile OK: actually compiles
// Runtime Error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
var currentPrinterOptional: PMPrinter? = nil
PMSessionGetCurrentPrinter(printSession, &currentPrinterOptional!)
```

### Resources

[Apple: Core Printing ⇗](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/applicationservices/core_printing)
[Apple: Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C ⇗](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/index.html)

*While the docs have useful information, a workable implementation for `UnsafeMutablePointer<PMPrinter>` with typealias as `UnsafeMutablePointer<OpaquePointer>` has been elusive.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`PMPrinter` and `PMPaper` are defined in the PrintCore framework
as pointer to an "incomplete type"

```
typedef struct OpaquePMPrinter*         PMPrinter;
typedef struct OpaquePMPaper*           PMPaper;
```

Those are imported into Swift as `OpaquePointer`, and are a bit
cumbersome to use.

The second argument to `PMSessionGetCurrentPrinter()` is a pointer to
a *non-optional* `PMPrinter` variable, and in Swift it must be 
initialized before being passed as an inout argument. One possible way
to initialize a null-pointer is to use `unsafeBitCast`.

The easiest way to get the `PMPaper` objects from the array seems to
be to use `CFArrayGetValueAtIndex()` instead of bridging it to a 
Swift array. That returns a `UnsafeRawPointer` which can be converted
to an `OpaquePointer`.

This worked in my test:

```
let printInfo = NSPrintInfo.shared()
let printSession = PMPrintSession(printInfo.pmPrintSession())

var currentPrinter = unsafeBitCast(0, to: PMPrinter.self)
PMSessionGetCurrentPrinter(printSession, &currentPrinter);

var paperListUnmanaged: Unmanaged<CFArray>?
PMPrinterGetPaperList(currentPrinter, &paperListUnmanaged)
guard let paperList = paperListUnmanaged?.takeUnretainedValue() else {
    fatalError()
}
for idx in 0..<CFArrayGetCount(paperList) {
    let paper = PMPaper(CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(paperList, idx))!
    var width = 0.0, height = 0.0
    PMPaperGetWidth(paper, &width)
    PMPaperGetHeight(paper, &height)
    print(width, height)
}
```

Comment: The info you provided was helpful to complete a [Core Printing Example](https://github.com/marc-medley/004.42Apple_CorePrintingExample) and create Swift code samples similar to Apple's related Technical Notes (TN2155 & TN2248) which currently have only Objective-C code listings. Thanks.