# How can I use Swift objects as UnsafeMutablePointer<OpaquePointer?> to a C function

Tags: c, swift, pointers, unsafemutablepointer

There is a C struct:

```
struct SomeStruct;
```

And there is a C function which uses this struct as double pointer parameter:

```
C_exampleFunction(struct SomeStruct** someClass)
```

I would like to pass any Swift class or object to this function in order to use its functionality. However the C function on the Swift side only accepts UnsafeMutablePointer as argument:

```
mySwiftFunction(for obj: AnyObject) {
   let objUnsafeMutableRawPointer = Unmanaged.passUnretained(obj).toOpaque()
   let objOpaquePointer = OpaquePointer(objUnsafeMutableRawPointer)
   let someClassArg = UnsafeMutablePointer<OpaquePointer?>(objOpaquePointer)

   C_exampleFunction(someClassArg)
}
```

The code has always produce some memory error even if I deallocate the pointers. 
My main question is how can I add objects as UnsafeMutablePointer to a C function like this above?

I checked these sources (but no luck):

- https://tech.bakkenbaeck.com/post/swift-c-interop
- https://www.sitepoint.com/using-legacy-c-apis-swift/
- https://www.uraimo.com/2016/04/07/swift-and-c-everything-you-need-to-know/#pointers-conversion
- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/unsafemutablepointer
- https://swift.org/migration-guide-swift3/se-0107-migrate.html
- [How to use UnsafeMutablePointer<OpaquePointer> in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44893912/how-to-use-unsafemutablepointeropaquepointer-in-swift)
  -https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/imported_c_and_objective-c_apis/using_imported_c_functions_in_swift

Error what I get is:

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x6ba571ac0)
```

Thank you for your answers, feedbacks and especially your time in advance.

Comment: use void pointer to pass the reference to the struct. Then in the function you can use it as you need

Comment: Hey @P__J__ thanks for the quick response. However not sure I get it. What kind of Void pointer are mean? The function on the Swift side only accepts argument which has UnsafeMutablePointer<OpaquePointer?> type.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question.  The C function signature means it  expects a `**` to `SomeStruct`.  What is that struct?  How would "any Swift class or object" be related to that structure?  If you used a void ptr to pass a Swift object, the C function would still be very limited in what it could do with it.

Comment: Agreed that it feels you're skipping over some critical part of your question. You can't pass arbitrary pointers to something that expects `struct SomeStruct**`. The language here wouldn't matter; the types have to match or how could that work. So it's not clear how `mySwiftFunction` works if you pass it random types. Your `mySwiftFunction` function also isn't defined behavior (you can't create pointers this way in Swift). What kind of struct does this function expect, and why do you believe you can pass arbitrary types to it?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. First of all thank you for your time and help, especially the dedicated answer. You are right the question here is missing one important information. I get this function from a C library what I would like to use in a project which was written in Swift. And it was mainly a question whether I can use it like this? Because the only way I can use that method is if I somehow use this OpaquePointer. The only thing what I know about this method is that I can only add objects to it and for that it uses a struct type double pointer.

Answer (score 1):

I think one can do relatively little with a Swift object passed to a C function via an incomplete type pointer, but if you need to do that, you are on a right track.

One problem I see with the code in your question is the line

```
let someClassArg = UnsafeMutablePointer<OpaquePointer?>(objOpaquePointer)
```

Here `someClassArg` is still a pointer to `obj` that was passed in to `mySwiftFunction()`, it's just cast to a different pointer type.  However, `C_exampleFunction()` needs a pointer to a pointer to `obj`.  Thus the code is most likely going to crash.

You can resolve this by replacing the problematic line with

```
let someClassArg = UnsafeMutablePointer<OpaquePointer?>.allocate(capacity: 1)
someClassArg.pointee = objOpaquePointer
```

There are other approaches, too.  For example, you could pass `objOpaquePointer` using `inout` syntax; it would need to be a `var` for that to work, though.  You could also avoid using `Unmanaged` like this:

```
let objUnsafeMutablePtr = UnsafeMutablePointer<AnyObject>.allocate(capacity: 1)
objUnsafeMutablePtr.pointee = obj
var objOpaquePtr : OpaquePointer! = OpaquePointer(objUnsafeMutablePtr)
C_exampleFunction(&objOpaquePtr)
```

(here we pass the opaque pointer as `inout`).

Regardless of which approach is taken, one should be very careful about the lifetime of `obj`.  For example, if you use `Unmanaged`, you may want to use `passRetained()` (and then `takeRetainedValue()` when retrieving the object), but that depends on your use case.

Here is another helpful resource about manual memory management:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/swift_standard_library/manual_memory_management